# How to create a hook using an object change dependency

Tags: reactjs, three.js

In my threejs app, I want to use a callback when my camera zoom changed in order to update an a ui zoom slider  .

I setted up a useCallback, but I have a mistake error :
Variable 'camera' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

```js
    export const SceneComponent = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
        const reactCanvas = useRef(null); 
        let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

        useEffect(() => {
            let width = reactCanvas.current.clientWidth;
            let height = reactCanvas.current.clientHeight;
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 1, 10000);
        }, [reactCanvas]);

        const handleCameraZoomChanged = useCallback(() => {
            console.log('Camera zoom changed');
        }, [camera.zoom]);

    return (
        <div className='scene-component'>
            <Toast ref={toastReload} />
            <PlayerBtn />
            <SliderSpeed />
            <SliderTimeline />
            <SliderZoom />
            <canvas className='canvas-holder' ref={reactCanvas} {...rest} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

I don't know if this really a nice way , but I tried it as follow , and know I have a mistake :
Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
on this line:
`CameraZoom.current = camera.zoom;`

```js
    export const SceneComponent = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
        const reactCanvas = useRef(null); 
        const CameraZoom = useRef(null); 

        let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;

        useEffect(() => {
            let width = reactCanvas.current.clientWidth;
            let height = reactCanvas.current.clientHeight;
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 1, 10000);

        const renderScene = () => {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            CameraZoom.current = camera.zoom;
        };
        }, [reactCanvas]);

        const handleCameraZoomChanged = useCallback(() => {
            console.log('Camera zoom changed');
        }, [CameraZoom.current]);

    return (
        <div className='scene-component'>
            <Toast ref={toastReload} />
            <PlayerBtn />
            <SliderSpeed />
            <SliderTimeline />
            <SliderZoom />
            <canvas className='canvas-holder' ref={reactCanvas} {...rest} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Could you share the entire component/hook? It seems you are declaring `camera` after having used it.

Comment: @vlk I updated code